# dynamically create array of custom structures

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc, calloc

I have a vector3 defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} vec3;
```

and then I have a few of them in this data structure:

```
typedef struct sprite {
    cg_quad* quad;
    vec3 scale;
    vec3 pos;
    vec3 angl;
}cg_sprite;
```

and here's that quad for good measure:

```
typedef struct {
    vec3 angles;
    GLshort vertex_count;
    GLfloat vertices[12];
    GLfloat colors[16];
    GLshort indices[6];
    GLfloat tex_coords[8];
} cg_quad;
```

I have a function that just takes a pointer to the sprite and suppose to create one then return it. Something simple like this:

```
cg_sprite* cg_sprite_new(const float x_pos, const float y_pos, const float z_pos, const float w, const float h) {
     cg_sprite* out = calloc(1, sizeof(cg_sprite));
     v3MakeFromElems(&out->scale, w, h, 1);
     v3MakeFromElems(&out->pos, x_pos, y_pos, z_pos);
     v3MakeFromElems(&out->angl, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

     v3PrintS(&out->scale);
     v3PrintS(&out->pos);
     v3PrintS(&out->angl);

     return out;
}
```

this works for one. I would like to allocate an array of sprites that I can update and use.

something like this:

```
sprite_count = 1;
cg_sprite* sprites;


sprite = calloc(1, sprite_count * sizeof(cg_sprite*));

for(int i = 0; i < sprite_count; i++) {
  sprites[i] = *cg_sprite_new(xpos, ypos, zpos, width, height);
}
```

then iterate through them like so.

```
for(int i = 0; i < sprite_count; i++) {
   vPrintS(sprites[i]->pose, "sprite index %d\n");
}
```

writing out the code like above, the allocation in the first loop doesn't work. If I don't calloc the size of the array first I get a seg fault.

If I do add the calloc, I get a

```
*** Error in `executable/main': corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000001a15670 ***
```

Any advise on sorting this out?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that strike me as a bit weird in your code snippets. Though I'm not sure any of them is causing your error.

1. `vPrintS(sprites[i]->pose, "sprite index %d\n");` Lools like a typical printf type va-args function with a `%d` specifier but no following argument to match.
2. `vPrintS(sprites[i]->pose, "sprite index %d\n");` sprites[i] is of type cg_sprite which has a `pos` member but no `pose` member.
3. `sprite = calloc(1, sprite_count * sizeof(cg_sprite*));` Are you meaning to assign the return value of calloc to `sprite` or `sprites`? I can't se that you are declaring `sprite` anywhere.

If you need more to get back on track I suggest you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)